# capital letter with acro

Tags: acro

What im trying to do it's to have a non capital E at the end of the scrip:

```
 % arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{CNO}{ short = CNO , long = Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones }
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{ short = \ensuremath{e_0} , long = Esperanza de vida al nacer , sort = e_0 } 
\begin{document}
\Ac{CNO} foo. Pero si \ac{e0} bar.
\end{document}
```

I want this text `Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones (CNO) foo`. `Pero si esperanza de vida al nacer (e0) bar`. Without 'Esperanza' with the capital E, just the e....

Comment: `long=esperanza de vida al nacer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the `acro` package works is that it has a method to uppercase initial letters (although beware that this doesn't work for accented letters!), so the base form of the long form should *not* be capitalized.  Then you use `\ac` or `\Ac` to use the uncapitalized and capitalized versions of the acronym, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{CNO}{ short = CNO , long = Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones }
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{ short = \ensuremath{e_0} , long = esperanza de vida al nacer , sort = e_0 } 
\begin{document}

\Ac{CNO} foo. 

Pero si \ac{e0} bar.

% these examples reverse the capitalization (as an example)
% the `l` forces re-use of the long form.

\acl{CNO} foo. 

Pero si \Acl{e0} bar.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]